# angular js - using filter in select, not returning the correct set

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter a selection list:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<select ng-model="targetToMap" required="true" 
ng-options="code.instructions_short for code in targetCodes   |filter:targetCodes.environment=2"
    ></select>
<div>
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {  
$scope.targetCodes = [
{"fid":"1","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.1"},
{"fid":"2","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.2"},
{"fid":"3","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.3"},
{"fid":"4","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.4"},
{"fid":"5","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.1"},
{"fid":"6","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.2"},
{"fid":"7","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.3"},
{"fid":"8","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.4"}
];
}
```

For some reason the filter appears to applying to both FID and ENVIRONMENT, so it returns a list including fid=2 as well as the 4 records where environment=2.  I put the filter inline to simplify the code.  What's wrong with this picture?

A jsfiddle can be found here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BobNoel/kTYJg/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you are using the wrong syntax for [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter).

Try replacing your filter with

```
| filter: {environment: '2'}
```

This will look for only objects in your array that have the property `environment` set to 2. Currently I don't know why it is doing what it's doing, but `targetCodes` doesn't have the `environment` property so the filter doesn't seem to make a lot of sense in general, even if it was using correct syntax.

**Edit**

Quick experiment shows that filtering on the original

```
targetCodes.environment=2
```

actually sets `targetCodes.environment` to `2`, and also evaluates to `2`. So this was equivalent to filtering with

```
| filter: 2
```

Comment: That's the ticket.  The code was a little too hastily put together so it's a little wonky, but you are correct about the syntax problem.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To filter properties, you should use:

`filter: { name: 'val'}`

You can see it in the first comment on the [filter docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) (Yes, its not necessarily "documented")

So, in your code, should be:

```
<select ng-model="targetToMap" required="true" ng-options="code.instructions_short for code in targetCodes | filter: {environment:  '2'}">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTYJg/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="targetToMap" required="true" ng-options="code.instructions_short for code in targetCodes">
      <option value="">-- Select Instructions --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  var allTargetCodes =[
      {"fid":"1","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.1"},
      {"fid":"2","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.2"},
      {"fid":"3","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.3"},
      {"fid":"4","environment":"1","instructions_short":"Script1.4"},
      {"fid":"5","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.1"},
      {"fid":"6","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.2"},
      {"fid":"7","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.3"},
      {"fid":"8","environment":"2","instructions_short":"Script2.4"}
  ];

  function filterTargetCodes() {
    $scope.targetCodes = [];
    angular.forEach(allTargetCodes, function(row) {
      if (row.environment != "2") {
        return;
      }
      $scope.targetCodes.push(row);
    });
  };

  filterTargetCodes();
}
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7CYMN9?p=preview)